# Mysql query with many to many

Tags: mysql

I have Eventos table which is related to Instituciones (many to many) using evento_institucion.

```
eventos       instituciones      evento_institucion
-------       -------------      ------------------
id            id                 id
name          name               evento_id
                                 institucion_id
```

Eventos is related with inscripciones table (one to many)

```
inscripciones
-------------
id
evento_id
code
```

Now, I need a SQL-query that lists inscripciones table, but I need to know eventos.name and lists of instituciones.name related to eventos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a query that returns a single row per 'inscripciones', with the following columns:

- eventos.name
- (any columns of inscripciones)
- a single column containing a list of instituciones.names

Then I assume the last one (the list of names) is giving you the most trouble. This can be done using MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Something similar to the following might work:

```
SELECT inscripciones.id, inscripciones.code, eventos.name, GROUP_CONCAT(instituciones.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM inscripciones, eventos, evento_institucion, instituciones
WHERE inscripciones.evento_id = eventos.id
  AND eventos.id = evento_institucion.evento_id
  AND evento_institucion.institucion_id = instituciones.id
GROUP BY inscripciones.id;
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want to see the rows related to a certain instituciones.id, but still want to have the column with ALL the instutuciones.names for the given inscripcion? I think that may require a subquery. In that case, it may be useful to edit your question to clarify what exactly you need, or even post a new question. If the above answer satisfies your original question, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
select i.*, ev.name, ins.name 
from inscripciones i
join evento_institucion ei on i.evento_id = ei.evento_id
join eventos e on ei.evento_id = e.id
join instituciones ins on ei.institucion_id = ins.id
```